# Asking if solution has been found

Tags: support

I have the same question as one that was posted several years ago, with no solution.

I'd like to ask the author if they found a solution in the meantime, but I understand that is not a legitimate reply (*avoid … Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers*).

What is the correct way to ask about that?

Comment: If the question has not been answered, you submit a new question, and hopefully provide more details than the author of the original question.  If you get an answer, that you for example accept, the community should close the original question as a duplicate of your question allowing more people to receive the correct answer.

Comment: Don't ignore the signals people. It is hard to directly contact someone, right? Dang near impossible with no private messages and all these rules about what you can and cannot put in a comment or an answer. This is not because of asshole design (hey, I did not coin that term), this is because it is intended that you do not directly contact other people. The only correct answer to this is: don't even try.

Comment: If you ask a question and you come up with an answer (on your own or based on answers it receives) that's better than any of the existing answers, please pay it forward and self-answer. Don't force some other programmer to be [this guy](https://xkcd.com/979/) if you can help it.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients) (979)